# Sharing files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

When I share files to my home group, I find the the other users are prompted to enter my username/password to access my resource. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must modify access right at folder for Everyone.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this cause a security threath if you also share files over the internet?

Comment: `Everyone` does not include `Anonymous`. (This may be changed in Group Policy Editor though.)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to edit any group policies. Read this tutorial and go to the *Configure HomeGroup Connections* section.
[How to Customize Network Sharing Settings in Windows 7](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-customize-network-sharing-settings-windows-7)

Most probably, your computer is set to "Use user accounts and passwords to connect to other computers" instead of letting Windows to manage homegroup connections.