# windows 7 sharing files on home network

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

Home network
Windows 7 on a laptop

I am trying to share a folders in my personal account on a laptop I have from work. My account has administrator privileges.

create folder on desktop
right click share

I followed the instructions from the link below and set the permissions to everyone.

[Sharing files in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/14214/sharing-files-in-windows-7)

I saw a reference to a home group. I am not sure what that is. I do not have any of that set up. I cannot see the folder from another pc.

There is a share folder that was set up with my image, that I do not have access to. So I know that share folders work. I want to create a new share folder. Even if I can get that one to work, I would like to have my own.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? you mention the instructions you are supposed to execute but you do not tell us what the problem was

Comment: Your post is somewhat confusing. Can you please [edit] it so it forms a question? In order to get a good answer, it is helpful to know as much relevant detail about the computers involved and what you have tried on each computer so far.

Comment: I don't really know what Home Groups are for - though I recently setup a share for someone from their Win7 box - first thing I did was turn off Home Groups. Also you may want to make sure your Windows Firewall isn't trolling you.

Answer (score 0):

In Start, type `Network and Sharing Center` and go there. 
Near the top left, select `Change advanced sharing settings.`

Select `Turn on network discovery` and `Turn on file and printer sharing.`

[image: Advanced Sharing settings]